# mod rewrite with get requests

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having issue passing get variables.

`index?p=calendar` refers to `calendar.php` located in `pages/calendar.php` and `index.php` is in root.

my URL is `localhost/researchportal/calendar/11/2011`

Calendar has 2 get variables, month and year. i.e `calendar.php?month=11&year=11`

here is my rule, but its not working.

```
RewriteRule ^calendar/([0-9]+)$/([0-9]+)$    index.php?p=calendar&month=$1&year=$2 [L]
```

I also tried

```
RewriteRule ^calendar/([0-9]+)$/([0-9]+)$    pages/calendar.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]
```

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /researchportal/
RewriteRule ^/calendar/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=calendar [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^users/login /researchportal/pages/login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^users/logout /researchportal/pages/logout.php [L]
RewriteRule ^users/register logout.php [L]

RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=profile&usr_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/edit/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=edit&usr_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^calendar/([0-9]+)$/([0-9]+)$`

Why are you ending ( $ ) it twice?

`^` starts and expression and `$` ends it. There is no reason to have neither in the middle of an expression.

```
RewriteRule ^calendar/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$    pages/calendar.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]
```

Should work better. If you for some reason would also want some query variables in the url, you can replace `[L]` with `[L,QSA]` aswell.

Comment: I'm kind of new to mod-rewrite, I thought that $ was part of the expression. Now I know that it ends the expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you have an additional $ character.

```
RewriteRule ^calendar/([0-9]+) *$* /([0-9]+)$    index.php?p=calendar&month=$1&year=$2 [L]
```